# How to fix a GRUB Boot-loader that does not recognize a partition without a fresh install?

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I was running two separate partitions of Linux (Ubuntu and Linux Mint) and Windows XP when I deleted my Ubuntu partition through Easus partition manager on XP due to simple stupidity. This erased my Grub bootloader, but I managed to install Grub Legacy from my Linux Mint Live CD. However, I cannot access my XP partition, and when I try to update GRUB boot-loader through Linux Mint, I receive an error message. I cannot perform a clean install, so I need to know how can I fix my GRUB Boot-loader through Linux Mint, so that it can recognize my Windows XP partition.

Comment: do you have a live cd or usb?

Comment: I have a live cd.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use "boot-repair" which is a graphical program that lets you repair most grub-related issues such as yours.

Check out this guide on how to install it and use it to fix your bootloader.
Although this guide is for ubuntu, Mint is based and completely compatible with ubuntu, so you are safe to follow that guide.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

make sure to select your drive and your mint partition as your drive/boot partition

Comment: Thank you Sam for answering my question, but I have a problem when using Boot Repair. The error reads, "Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of The OS now in use - Linux Mint 13 Maya (sda5). Then try again." 
How can I solve this?

Comment: do you have internet connection when doing that?

Comment: Yes, I do have an internet connection while using boot repair.

Comment: try to execute "sudo apt-get update" to update the repos list before running boot-repair

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB or whatever, open a command line, and run the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` 
(if you don't want GRUB on your primary hard drive, change sda to whichever hard drive you want it installed on). 
In your case, it should be sda

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231940/my-install-did-not-install-the-grub-loader-and-i-also-can-not-get-to-windows-7-e)

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your grub configuration

```
sudo update-grub
```

this will add your windows to grub menu

Answer (score 0):

First I tried with `sudo os-prober` and `sudo update-grub` and it didn't recognize my windows partition.

Finally I solved this problem following steps of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Install boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Push "Recommended repair"
And put in a terminal some commands as it suggested.

I think my Grub doesn't recognize windows due to a bad shutdown, and it solved the problem.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `/etc/default/grub` file with sudo permission

Add at the end of the file (or anywhere you want) the following line: `

> **GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false**

PS: check first if there is a line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`. In that case, just change `true` with `false`.