# My install did not install the grub loader and I also can not get to windows 7 either

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, installation

I did a new install on Ubuntu 12.04 and when it was finishing it did not install the grub loader and this installation was over a previous installation where the partition should have been formatted.  The install will not install to any partition I have.  And with no grub I am unable to get to my Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB or whatever, open a command line, and run the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (if you don't want GRUB on your primary hard drive, change sda to whichever hard drive you want it installed on).